# Create Calendar Webpart on Subsite

Tags: web-part, calendar

I have a top level calendar that I am running.  It will allow the users for the entire organization to put events via divisions they may need to. I have figured out how to get the webpart down to a lower level using Sharepoint designer, however when the person goes to add a event, I get an "Error - List does not exist" I'm assuming this is because it's at a higher level.  (by the way works fine in list view, just not in calendar view).  So here is what I need to do, either a fix it so I can add an event via the calendar view, or b find a way to create a link right below the month year, above the days, that will open a blank page back to my original form.  That way when the user clicks "To add an event click here" a new tab will open up directly to the location of where they need to add the event.

I have also already tried creating a new aspx page and removing the masterpage, however that errors out as well as I believe our administrator has forced us to have a masterpage with an aspx page.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score -1):

Are u able to create lists on this site ?

Have u got the Team Collaboration Lists feauture Enabled?

U need to link your add a new calendar event to your top level site. This linking is missing as understood.

Something like you can manipulate the top level site with list view webpart that points to parent top level list.

Make sure this will only be respective to this calendar list you had created.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How would you link that?  The Team Collaboration Lists feature is enabled.